Summing equal geometries with identical columns in QGIS
I have two vector layers with line geometries which share column names. The one is a subset of the other, and even though they share the same columns, they differ in their values.
I would now like to add the values of the subset to the other layer, creating a new layer which has a sum of the values of the two layers in it, where they overlap.
I found the tool 'join attributes by location (summary)', and I thought it would do exactly that when I give in the parameters as in the image, but it doesn't calculate the sum, instead it gives us an unchanged value.
What am I doing wrong, and what would I need to do instead?


Do the features in the "subset" layer always match the primary layer i.e. the geometry of a feature in the subset layer has a corresponding feature in the primary layer (all vertices the same)?

As said by @Aquamarine maybe you should use a more lax condition to join both geometries. This kind of tasks are more suitable for PostgreSQL/PostGIS

@Aquamarine Yes, they have identical geometries! I will try to switch to SQL. Thanks for helping!

Virtual layers are a good way to solve your problem.
In this example a layer layer1 and a layer layer2 share attributes lanes of type integer and surface of type character. For calculating the sum of numeric columns you can use the + operator --> sum_lanes. For concatenating character columns you can use the concat function --> concat_surface. For the join use the ST_Equals() method to join based on the same geometry or you can use the same id if they share some id like a.osm_id = b.osm_id.
SELECT 
    a.osm_id,
    a.lanes as lanes_a,
    b.lanes as lanes_b,
    a.lanes + COALESCE(b.lanes, 0) as sum_lanes,
    a.surface as surface_a,
    b.surface as surface_b,
    concat(a.surface, " | ", b.surface) as concat_surface,
    a.geometry
FROM layer1 a
LEFT JOIN layer2 b
ON ST_Equals(a.geometry, b.geometry)


thank you very much! I will try this!

I managed to create a virtual layer with a column in which the line features, which have equal geometries, have the sum of the two geometries using this query:select  a.DTV + b.DTV as DTV,  a.geometry from layer1 a left join layer2 b on st_equals(a.geometry, b.geometry). However, all other geometries now have a 'NuLL'-value. How can I keep the values for the objects which are not overlapping with the second layer?

using a left join should give you all from layer a and all matching from layer b. NULL values in the not overlapping features are not explainable because of the join. Maybe they are Null beforehand?

or do you mean with all other  geometries actually all other features and you want to have the value of DTV of all features from layer a in the result column?

Yes, exactly! The resulting layer should be more or less a copy of layer 1, but the values, where there is overlap with layer 2 should be the sum of layer 1 and layer 2.

I have updated the answer. You can do: a.DTV + COALESCE(b.DTV, 0) as DTV

Thank you! As my question here divides from the starting question here (as I asked for a tool in QGIS, not for SQL specifics) I opened a specific question to this problem here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/483799/qgis-sql-virtual-layer-how-to-change-values-where-two-geometries-are-equal-ot/483800#483800), where the solution is also the coalesce-function. Now I will need to read about it :) Thank you very much for your help!
